# Three.js spotlight target direction not being updated

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to emulate a car's headlights, but can't seem to get the spotlight to update its target position. I need it pointing forward, but by increasing the intensity, it seems to still be pointing down. It looked like the light is AROUND the headlight and not pointing to its target. Even the helper is telling me it's pointing forward, but looking at the evidence, that does not seem to be the case. I want the spotlight to go in the direction of the helper.
[image]

code:

```
var carHeadlight1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xF2E66A, 10, 8, 9.2);

carHeadlight1.castShadow = true;
    carHeadlight1.target.position.set(-0.25, 0.5, -3);
    carHeadlight1.target.updateMatrixWorld();
    carHeadlight1.position.y -= 0.7;
    carHeadlight1.position.x -= 0.3;
    carHeadlight1.position.z -= 0.8;
    const spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(carHeadlight1);
    scene.add(spotLightHelper);
```

Comment: Have a look at this forum post: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/lights-for-car-headlight/9410/4

Comment: `var carHeadlight1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xF2E66A, 10, 8, 9.2);` seems to be my problem. The 4th argument is doing weird things, as it's meant to be a value in radians. I thought it narrowed the light beam, but it obviously does something much different. If I remove the `9.2`, then the light looks MUCH better.